# Luis Training and associating it with intents

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

Currently, I have a few intents, one of which is "Greeting", and I have "good morning" trained to fire that intent.  However, "Sunday morning, "Monday morning", etc... always fire this intent, incorrectly.  I have spent the morning training "{Datetime} morning" to associate with the other intent, however, it is not learning.  Is there a better method, or do i have just to spend more time, typing the same intent over and over again to make LUIS associate it with the other intent?

Comment: What are the utterances that 'Greeting' intent should fire? Only 'good morning' or you have a list of utterances?

Comment: "Greeting" intent fires on "hello", "hey there", "good morning" and other variations of this. The problem is "Sunday morning" is being confused with "good morning", and causing an issue.

Comment: The approach of {Datetime} morning can be used to identify them separately. Not as a separate intent, but as a separate route in the same intent 'Greeting' that has an entity.

Comment: That is a good approach, and will add it in as a fallback! i spent some time, training, and eventually it caught all the days of the week and is being handled by the appropriate intent.  Thanks for your suggestion!